# How to transpose the columns of a row into a single column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I hope you are well.

I present myself. I am Yassine, PhD student in France and currently working in Food safety lab in France.

I need some help with a dataframe on R if possible.

Currently, I have the retention times (RT) in rows associated with each of the fragments (in column).

I would like to have all the fragments of the same row in a single column, with the same RT.

Here is what I have:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI67w.png [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30E9z.png)

**Here is what I would like to do in R**:

[image]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ5Kf.png] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30E9z.png)

I thank you in advance for any advice or guidance !
I wish you all a very good day.

Respectfully,
Yassine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unlist` and subset the columns.

```
x <- data.frame(RT=1:3, F1=4:6, F2=7:9)

data.frame(x[1], F=unlist(x[-1]))
#    RT F
#F11  1 4
#F12  2 5
#F13  3 6
#F21  1 7
#F22  2 8
#F23  3 9
```

or if order matters.

```
data.frame(RT=rep(x[,1], each=ncol(x)-1), F=as.vector(t(x[-1])))
#  RT F
#1  1 4
#2  1 7
#3  2 5
#4  2 8
#5  3 6
#6  3 9
```

Comment: This was very helpfull thanks ! However, what is the purpose of each=ncol(x)-1 and  F=as.vector(t(x[-1] ? Why the argument "-1" ??

Comment: Beside the Fragment columns, there is also the RT column, which needs to be excluded, what could be done with `-1`, when RT is in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack`. (Data borrowed from GKi)

```
cbind(x[1], F=unname(stack(x[-1])[-2]))
#   RT F
# 1  1 4
# 2  2 5
# 3  3 6
# 4  1 7
# 5  2 8
# 6  3 9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = matches("Fragment \\d+"),
                    names_to = "Fragment",
                    values_to = "value")
```